# Laravel chosen-select retrieving old value from the form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, laravelcollective

I am trying to retrieve old value from my form on the edit form, but it seems impossible to find an answer, because everyone in the world decided to use Form::select from laravelcollective/html library. I am trying to use the regular HTML to work this, and it's not able to retrieve old value from the form.

This is my HTML Code.

```
                        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Role*</label>
                            <select name="roles[]" data-placeholder="Choose a Role for this User..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                @foreach ($roles as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ in_array($key, old("roles")) ? "selected":"") }} >{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

This is my controller code.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $roles = Role::get()->pluck('name', 'id');
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles'));
}
```

I am trying to convert the following into regular html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('role', trans('global.users.fields.role').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('role[]', $roles, old('role') ? old('role') : $user->role->pluck('id')->toArray(), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'required' => '']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('role'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('role') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The old value is for when you have submitted the form and have mistakes in the form, and it populates it with old `session` data. as far as i can see you dont use it this way. you only fetch from the DB. so therefor you dont need the old function.

Comment: Where is your $request->flash() ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group {{ $errors->has('role') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="role" class="control-label">Role *</label>

  <select class="form-control select2" name="role[]" id="role" required multiple>
    @foreach ($roles as $id => $label)
      <option value="{{ $id }}" @if (collect(old('role', $user->role->pluck('id') ?? []))->contains($id)) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $label }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>

  <span class="help-block">
  @if ($errors->has('role'))
    {{ $errors->first('role') }}
  @endif
  </span>
</div>
```

In your controller's update/store function, make sure you either use the built-in validation methods, which will populate the session on any errors.

or

If you have other checks, make sure you return the input when redirecting back.

```
return redirect()->back()
    ->withInput() // <- return input with redirect, will populate session
    ->with('error', 'Persist failed'); // <- optional
```

Comment: I am getting following error. "Call to a member function pluck() on null"

Comment: Ah, you use `role` instead of `roles` for the relation name, changed that in the answer.